# How to get rid of an extra drive in "My Computer" showing up with question mark

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I've tried all sorts of things and been stumped...any suggestions welcome! I'm starting to contemplate reinstalling Windows now...

I have a drive in my computer that I might have added by mounting a VHD, but I can't seem to get rid of it now:

[image]

What I've tried so far (keeping a running list because these methods might work for others):

- Right clicking on the drive and clicking on Disconnect (it wasn't an option)
- In the command line: subst, net use (not a network drive)
- Looking in Disk Management (drive was not listed)
- In Explorer, going to Tools | Folder Options and on the View tab checking the "Hide empty drives in Computer folder" option. ([source](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/129385-%22Ghost%22-disk))
- In the registry under HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices, removing the \DosDevices\L: key ([source](http://diddy.boot-land.net/firadisk/files/mounteddevices.htm))
- In that same key, removing all the \??\Volume{...} keys
- [Made hidden devices visible in Device Manager](http://www.theeldergeek.com/show_hidden_devices_in_device_manager.htm), then uninstalled disconnected Disk drives and Storage Volumes.
- Looking in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-do-i-get-rid-of-non-existent-hard-drive-local/a022b807-89b9-4377-9310-6c8239ca2b82?page=2) (nothing there)
- [Ran `mountvol.exe` and `mountvol l: /D` in the command line](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1051267) (didn't list L:)
- Collecting all references to L: in the registry (`reg query HKLM /s /f "L:" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\reg.txt"`). Found a reference to Motorola XT912, went into Device Manager, deleted it. Drive still there.
- Tried [USB Oblivion](https://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/downloads/detail?name=usboblivion64-1.10.0.0.zip). Looks like it will ignore L: `Found drives (will be ignored): C: D: E: F: H: J: L:`
- **Ended up searching the registry again after all the above steps, and removing keys in the [ControlSet in DosDevices](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102985).**

Things that might be dangerous:

- [Removing all the hidden Storage volumes (including the ones that exist)](https://superuser.com/questions/379824/safe-to-remove-hidden-storage-volumes), as well as [all USB mass storage devices that were disconnected](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/553620-cant-get-rid-local-disk.html) (didn't work either)

Other things I looked at:

- In [Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7), the L: drive doesn't show up.
- In [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us), it does.
- I don't have Windows Office Click-to-Run.

Ideas welcome!

Comment: Does the drive show up if you [start Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7)? Did you try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) already?

Comment: Just tried it. Safe mode hides it, clean boot does not. Flummoxed.

Comment: More details are required. Judging from the screenshot you're running a 64-bit version Windows 7. Is the [Service Pack 1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1) installed? Is the system fully updated? What's the list of installed programs? When did you first notice the issue? Have you got any [restore points](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore)? Open a command prompt and run this command: `reg query HKLM /s /f "L:" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\reg.txt"` Then post here the full output.

Comment: Yes, Win7 64-bit with SP1. Should be fully updated. Was quite soon after I was playing with VHDs, but given the results of the registry query I'm not so sure that was the cause.

Comment: Here's the registry - I went ahead and removed things like "HTML:" to save you the trouble, but you can see that version if you want, too. http://pastebin.com/pi6eJKTW

Comment: The drive letter is associated to a Motorola DROID RAZR XT912 device. After enabling hidden/non-present devices, open the Device Manager and uninstall anything related. Should the drive still be there, try using [USB Oblivion](https://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/) to remove any additional traces of USB-connected drives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14857/discussion-between-and31415-and-chris).

Comment: Fixed! Wish you had an answer I could upvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Analysis

The first thing you will notice is that the drive appears in the **Other** group. If you were to try to open it, you would get the following error message:

> L:\ refers to a location that is unavailable. It could be on a hard drive on this computer, or on a network. Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted, or that you are connected to the Internet or your network, and then try again. If it still cannot be located, the information might have been moved to a different location.

When starting Windows in [Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) the extra drive wasn't there, but it would come back after starting the system normally or performing a [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us). This suggests third-party software shouldn't be involved.

### Collecting registry entries

The drive letter has to be referenced somewhere in the registry. By running the following command you can create a simple report:

```
reg query HKLM /s /f "L:" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\reg.txt"
```

What the command does is to scan the entire machine-related registry branch looking for anything containing the drive letter followed by a colon (i.e. `L:`).

After removing unrelated entries (such as those containing strings like `HTML:`), this was the output:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Portable Devices\Devices\WPDBUSENUMROOT#UMB#2&37C186B&0&STORAGE#VOLUME#_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MOTOROLA&PROD_XT912&REV_0000#014FCE0915017008&1#
    FriendlyName    REG_SZ    L:\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
    L:    REG_SZ    \Device\HarddiskVolume9

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\WpdBusEnumRoot\UMB\2&37c186b&0&STORAGE#VOLUME#_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MOTOROLA&PROD_XT912&REV_0000#014FCE0915017008&1#
    FriendlyName    REG_SZ    L:\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
    L:    REG_SZ    \Device\HarddiskVolume9

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Enum\WpdBusEnumRoot\UMB\2&37c186b&0&STORAGE#VOLUME#_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MOTOROLA&PROD_XT912&REV_0000#014FCE0915017008&1#
    FriendlyName    REG_SZ    L:\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
    L:    REG_SZ    \Device\HarddiskVolume9

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\WpdBusEnumRoot\UMB\2&37c186b&0&STORAGE#VOLUME#_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MOTOROLA&PROD_XT912&REV_0000#014FCE0915017008&1#
    FriendlyName    REG_SZ    L:\
```

There aren't many results. The first one contains some interesting bits:

```
USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_MOTOROLA&PROD_XT912
```

### Uninstalling non-present devices

By default, the Device Manager utility doesn't display devices which aren't connected to the computer. What you need to do is to open a command prompt as administrator, and run the following command:

```
set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1 & start devmgmt.msc
```

Then make sure to enable **Show hidden devices** on the **View** menu. The drive letter was associated to a **Motorola DROID RAZR XT912** device at some point, so uninstall anything related.

You might also want to use [USB Oblivion](https://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/downloads/list) in order to remove any extra leftovers. Make sure to get the 32-bit or 64-bit version matching your [operating system bitness](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218/en-us).

### Collecting registry entries - part 2

As expected, some entries were gone:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
    L:    REG_SZ    \Device\HarddiskVolume9

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
    L:    REG_SZ    \Device\HarddiskVolume9
```

The `DOS Devices` subkey can be used to associate device names used by applications to those used internally by the operating system. Each entry is a string value (`REG_SZ`) representing a symbolic link which gets created during the startup phase. In Windows 7, these are the values available by default:

```
AUX = \DosDevices\COM1
MAILSLOT = \Device\MailSlot
NUL = \Device\Null
PIPE = \Device\NamedPipe
PRN = \DosDevices\LPT1
UNC = \Device\Mup
```

My assumption is that the extra drive wasn't meant to show up; perhaps a driver bug or some other reason (e.g. an unexpected shutdown) prevented it from being removed automatically. Installing the latest driver from the official [Motorola support page](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/product_page/faqs/p/30,6720,8112) might avoid the problem in the future.

### Further reading

- [ControlSet00n](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960234.aspx)
- [REG: CurrentControlSet Entries PART 2: SessionManager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102985/en-us)
- [Device Manager does not display devices that are not connected to the Windows XP-based computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315539/en-us)

---

## Resolution

The fix is surprisingly simple, once you know where to look:

1. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7), type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   reg delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices" /v "L:" /f
   ```
2. Restart Windows to apply the changes.

### Further reading

- [What are Control Sets? What is CurrentControlSet?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100010/en-us)
- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)

Comment: The most epic answer I've ever received bar none. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest method:

1. Plug in a pendrive.
2. Change its drive letter to L: using disk management (diskmgmt.msc).
3. Change its letter to what it was earlier.

And L: will be gone.

Comment: This won't work because as far as the system is concerned, `L` is already in use and assigned to ***something***.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I'm having this issue right now and tried exactly this solution (having completely forgotten that I'd shot it down a few years ago), and for a moment there I thought it worked, but as soon as I refreshed Explorer, it reappeared. So I was right in that it doesn't work, but wrong in the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

A third party program [TweakNow PowerPack 2011](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/System-Enhancements/TweakNow-PowerPack-Portable.shtml) will get rid of the unwanted drive.
Look at the screenshot of all visible drives:[Look screenshot here](http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/TweakNow-PowerPack-Portable_12.png)

start the powerpack aplication, navigate to **Windows Secret** tab and click **Windows Explorer** icon and uncheck the **Local Disk (L:)**
 
Click the save icon.
Reboot.

Comment: Nice! I can't prove it works since we fixed the problem already, but hopefully this will help someone else. Seems like it's more of a hider than a remover.

Comment: @Chris This is more a head-buried-in-the-sand approach, rather than an actual solution. In fact, if you hide the drive letter you still won't be able to associate it to anything else. Anyway, the linked program is a 15-day trial. While free alternatives do exist, you could just enable a [related group policy setting](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2650) or [edit the registry manually](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938267.aspx).

Comment: @ISAAC If you open the Softpedia page, you'll notice it points to an external [broken link](http://tweaknow.com/download/PowerPack323_port.zip). The [official website](http://tweaknow.com/) doesn't provide any portable versions. In fact, last freeware version was `4.1.0` (archived page [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120503200112/http://tweaknow.com/)). The [program went sharewhare](http://web.archive.org/web/20120511082906/http://tweaknow.com/) (i.e. trial) with version `4.1.5`. Last released version is `4.3.1`, and it's clearly mentioned it's *not* freeware.

Comment: That will only hide the drive, it will not actually remove it. If you do something that requires adding a new drive letter (attaching a disk, changing partitions, etc.) then the drive letter (in this case `L`) will be unavailable because it is still in use ***somewhere***.

Answer (score -1):

just disable it.
Right click -> properties ->and search for disabling options.
You may have to go one or two level down to disable it.

Comment: building on hariths right click-> properties->hardware->properties->"change settings"->driver-> you the option to disable or uninstall

Comment: This response makes no sense. There are no “disabling options” for drives in Windows (at least not from My Computer). Moreover, if the drive is a “phantom” drive, then it will probably not have a Hardware tab in its Properties dialog.

Answer (score -1):

first right click on drive and click on eject then the other
steps to be followed are:

1. right click on folder
2. click on properties
3. click on hardware tab
4. click on properties
5. click on change settings
6. click on drivers tab
7. click on uninstall device

this is the method that worked for me
hope this helps you too.

Comment: You obviously didn't bother to read my comment to Harith's identical answer. ***There is no Hardware tab!***